# rendering class and 'normal' component together in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble with rendering this component (also I have no idea if it gets data from API correctly since it won't render):

```
class item_box extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: []
  }
}

function = () => {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  let output = []
  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3005/products/157963', true)
  request.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    this.setState(prevState => ({output: [...prevState.output, data]}))
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      console.log('ok');
    } else {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }
request.send()
}


render() {
  return (
    <ItemPanel>
<ItemBox>
  <BoxTitle>{this.state.output[0].brand}</BoxTitle>
  <BoxId>Id:774946</BoxId>
  <Details onClick={show_details}>Show more...</Details>
    <Inline>
      <Quantity type="number" defaultValue="1"></Quantity>
      <Icon>add_shopping_cart</Icon>
      </Inline>
      <AddItem>
    <Sfont>Add to cart</Sfont>
  </AddItem>
</ItemBox>
    <BoxImg src={require("./ucfnti1.jpg")} alt='img error'></BoxImg>
 </ItemPanel>
  );
}
}
```

together, with another component:

```
const item_details = (
<DetailsView id="details_view">
...
</DetailsView>
);
```

I was trying this:

```
function Items() {
return (
  [item_details, item_box]
);
}

export default Items;
```

to run it from my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Items from './DataHarvester'

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<Items />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Have also tried ( with and without the brackets):

```
ReactDOM.render([<App />, <Items />],document.getElementById('root'));
```

Sorry, but I'm a react newbie, how can I render that component?

Comment: By placing the component in your App component JSX? What am I missing? Please  put up an example on https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-architecture-tkrkb?fontsize=14

Comment: here u go, I appreciate help

Comment: Can't help. As I'm certain you can see, the REPL is broken and doesn't work. What's needed as suggested by the SO help page is a [SIMPLE, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can compose your components just like any other element,

```
ReactDOM.render(
  (<React.Fragment>
    <App /> 
    <item_details />
    <item_box />
  </React.Fragment>)
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

But I believe the two components should be inside the `App` component.